# Vertex AI doesn't give any update on Model Evaluation

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I was trying to evaluate a model I deployed in Vertex AI. I'm able to predict the data using deployed endpoint ID in the notebook. I was trying to do a batch prediction and the evaluation of the model. As per the documentation, I'm supposed to get an email regarding the success of the process. But I've not received any mail/update regarding the evaluation process even after a day. I am using a test data from BigQuery with 1000 rows to evaluate the model

[Screenshot from VertexAI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhW1F.png)

I am trying to create a model evaluation in Vertex AI using the Create Evaluation option